# Can't receive packets to raw socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp, raw-sockets

I'm writing raw socket client (which successfully sends UDP packets) and a server socket, The problem is in the server part.

Im creating a socket in the following way:

`int raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);`

also I tried it with IPPROTO_RAW, but get the same result and I'm binding it:

`bind(raw_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockstr, sizeof(sockstr))`

when trying to receive some packets using the socket, the only payload I receive is "E" (I think that means "Error"), or the socket continues listening but blocks and nothing happens.
How do I receive a UDP packet using a raw socket?
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
int server(){
    int raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if (raw_socket== -1){
        perror("Socket_creation_error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sockstr;
    sockstr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sockstr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockstr.sin_port = htons(9090);
    socklen_t s = (socklen_t)sizeof(sockstr);

    if (bind(raw_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockstr, sizeof(sockstr))< 0){
        perror("binding_err\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char* msg[256];
    memset(msg, 0, 256);

    recv(raw_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    printf(msg);
    return 0;
}

void main(){
    server();
}
```

Comment: if you are on linux and ufw (unix firewall) is running UDP packets are dropped by default

Comment: maybe u wanna show us what u have written

Comment: What is "E"? How do you get "E"?

Comment: You should post a [MCVE] and tell us on which system/priviledge the program is runned

Comment: DrPrItay, I have edited post and added code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As raw sockets manual says `user@host:~$ man 7 raw`:

> A  protocol  of  IPPROTO_RAW  implies enabled IP_HDRINCL and **is able to send** any IP protocol that is specified in the passed header.  **Receiving of all IP protocols via IPPROTO_RAW is not possible using raw sockets.**

Another important note also extracted from manual is:

> **Only processes with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW  capability are allowed to open raw sockets.**

And manual says too:

> Starting with Linux 2.2, **all IP header fields and options  can  be  set using  IP  socket  options**.   This means raw sockets are usually needed only for new protocols or protocols with no user interface (like ICMP).

Ok, assuming you need to have IP/UDP headers in hand, let's go to work :-)
First of all, we need to let some points clear:

- In your code above some `#include ...` headers are missing.
- *IPPROTO_RAW* (as manual says) cannot be used to receive all protocols.
- Why did you define socklen?  You could use it, for example, in *bind()*.
- `char *msg[SIZE]` ???    It's an array of char pointers! You need only an array of chars, like this: `char msg[SIZE]`.
- Remember, you are using RAW sockets and packets received from these sockets comes with **headers**. To print your message you need to do an offset in *msg* which corresponds to *ip* header plus *udp* header. (In code below, note that I've added `#include <linux/ip.h>` and `#include <linux/udp.h>` to obtain the headers's size).
- Finally, do a cleanup: in this case only *close()* the socket :-)

### The code ...

---

main.c

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/ip.h> /* for ipv4 header */
#include <linux/udp.h> /* for udp header */

#define ADDR_TO_BIND "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT_TO_BIND 9090

#define MSG_SIZE 256
#define HEADER_SIZE (sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr))

int main(void) {
    int raw_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in sockstr;
    socklen_t socklen;

    int retval = 0; /* the return value (give a look when an error happens)
                     */

    /* no pointer to array!
     * >> It was like "a variable that contains an address -- and in this
     *    address begins an array of chars"! */
    /* now it is simple an array of chars :-)  */
    char msg[MSG_SIZE];
    ssize_t msglen; /* return value from recv() */

    /* do not use IPPROTO_RAW to receive packets */
    if ((raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1; /* here there is no clean up -- retval was not used */
    }

    sockstr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockstr.sin_port = htons(PORT_TO_BIND);
    sockstr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR_TO_BIND);
    socklen = (socklen_t) sizeof(sockstr);

    /* use socklen instead sizeof()  Why had you defined socklen? :-)  */
    if (bind(raw_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &sockstr, socklen) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        retval = 1; /* '1' means "Error" */
        goto _go_close_socket;
    }

    memset(msg, 0, MSG_SIZE);

    if ((msglen = recv(raw_socket, msg, MSG_SIZE, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        retval = 1;
        goto _go_close_socket;
    }

    if (msglen <= HEADER_SIZE) /* msg  can't be lesser than header! */
        printf("No msg!\n");
    else {
        msg[msglen - 1] = '\0'; /* we need a null character at the end*/
        printf("Your msg _plus_ headers's size is: %s\n",
               msg + HEADER_SIZE);
    }

_go_close_socket:
    close(raw_socket);

    return retval;
}
```

Ok, now compile the program with:
`user@host:~$ gcc -o main main.c`
Execute it as root:
`root@host:~# ./main`
And in another terminal send a message with *nc*:
    *-u* specifies UDP to *nc*
`user@host:~$ nc -u 127.0.0.1 9090`
That is it!

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. It's very  helpful.

Comment: One thing is not still clarified to me is that if one wants to use raw sockets and catch all the protocols, not only UDP, why are we using IPPROTO_UDP?

Comment: @multiplayer1080 According to the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html), receiving of all protocols by using `IPPROTO_RAW` is not supported by raw sockets. However, it's possible to create another raw socket with a protocol like `IPPROTO_TCP`, for example.